# Why did posting a link to my SO question in chat lead to a very negative response?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

This particular question was asked by me with honest curiosity and earnest effort was put in forming it as well. Never mind how easy/difficult the solution turns out to be, it was a legitimate problem that I was facing.

Also there were no qualms about the effort put forth in forming the question and providing necessary relevant details. However, when the question was posted in the SO chat room, numerous people blasted if off, gleefully if I might add. Barring a small minority (the accepted answer was a well-explained solution), everyone ganged up against the question with their negative votes.

No matter where the OP is coming from, earnest effort put forth and genuine problems he/she faces should be recognized independent of his/her coding competence.

I hope to find some justice here (at meta) regarding this matter.

**Here is the link to question**: [Detecting end of input using std::getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673332/detecting-end-of-input-using-stdgetline).

**Here is the link to chat transcript**: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=12674757#12674757

I was very polite in introducing the question to the chatroom. I started off by posting the link and saying "I think it is an interesting question". I never spammed or commented out of my chance. Nor did I once point my finger at anyone  or make personal insults.

I thank everyone here very much for having shown solidarity. I understand the nature of SO chatrooms and the innate hostility involved, and that is exactly the issue I wanted to throw light on in the first place; **on how that hostility doesn't remain inside the chatrooms, but spills out to the main site as well**.

I admit I could have been more clear in my introduction of the question in the chatroom. I could have said that this is a problem that *I* am facing. But that was in no way to pretend  to be not the asker. Anyone who would see the asker profile would know in any case that the OP was me.

Comment: Can you post a link to the transcript where it was talked about in the chat room? That will provide context.

Comment: I will look for it presently. please bear with me for some time

Comment: Using the third person *"... by the OP"* about yourself feels a little odd to me. Like you are trying to pretend it is not your question.

Comment: I am not pretending not to be the OP. I thought that is the best way to put forth the question. I will make the edit if you suggest to make the clarification

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I have added the transcript

Comment: I don't think the third person thing impacts on the core question here. The final version of your question has, in my opinion, sufficient information and demonstration that you have been thinking about the problem yourself. But people are allowed to not like it and they are allowed to say so and they are allowed to vote it as they see it. If things don't go beyond that then you don't have a complaint; if they do go beyond that ... well, I'm not sure and we'll have to see that transcript first.

Comment: @dmckee I have added the transcript. Please notice the language used like "LOL" and "have -1"

Comment: @Servy I understand that. Hence I was very polite in introducing the question to the chatroom. I started off by posting the link and saying "I think it is an interesting question". I never spammed or commented out of my chance.

Comment: Looks like you got your feeling hurt and your question answered. If that is the worst thing that happens to you all month you're have a good month. Best to just move on.

Comment: As a side viewer, it looks like you just advertised your own question, kind of "chat spam". In their jargon it's  probably called "question dumper", something I never heard before, and the veteran chat users highly dislike it. You might have had better luck if your first sentence was something like "I posted this question but it did not get enough attention can you please have a look".

Comment: Also, why it took you two weeks to post this?

Comment: Again the phrasing you use there "I think it is an interesting question". doesn't make clear up front that it is *your* question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I was wondering what I should do about this issue I felt about. Today I finally decided to put it in meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @MartinSmith I admit I could have been more clear in my introduction of the question in the chatroom.

Comment: +1 for your question... I know how this feels

Comment: And keep in mind that whenever you put a question in front of an audience, they are going to respond. And that response might not always be as positive as you imagined it would be. The same goes for users presenting their questions here on Meta.

Comment: (sees the C++ tag) Well, **there's** your problem.

Comment: I'm glad I saw this, not because of any issues with chat, but because the accepted (and upvoted) answer appears to have been incorrect.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for your answer! I have accepted it as it correctly explains the reason for the problem and provides the solution as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chat ***tends*** to be a place for mindless social fun, note the preceding conversations. That said posting your question there is a bit like throwing it to the wolves.

Basically you went to a place where people go "to make fun", gave them something, and they ran with it.

Next time if you want added constructive attention for a question, consider using a bounty.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice!

Comment: C++ chat, anyway. Other chat rooms may actually care about programming :P

Comment: People should stay for a bit longer than the average fluff discussion in this chatroom to see there's _also_ programming discussion. :P